# Service Receiving Touch Events from all Activities on Phone?

Tags: android

I've seen applications that if you touch a certain part of the screen (i.e. very top left) they will launch an application. This can be done from the home screen, or any application on my screen. The best I can figure how they can do this is by having a service that receives all touch events, and then tests whether or not they are in the specified area? How would you do this? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The best I can figure how they can do this is by having a service that receives all touch events, and then tests whether or not they are in the specified area?

No.

> How would you do this?

A service cannot receive touch events, sorry.

> Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I believe that the apps in question were exploiting a security hole that has since been closed.

Comment: I just downloaded one of the applications today, and it seems to be working on Android 2.2. They've made a pretty handy application with it, and it has a service that runs in the background. They basically have it so that if I make a gesture on the bottom of my screen with any of my applications open, Then there application opens which allows me to make shortcuts to other programs. Can you think of any other way that something like this could be done? First place I looked is your books, but I didn't see any chapters specifically on TouchEvent manipulation like this.

Comment: @spierce7: "I just downloaded one of the applications today, and it seems to be working on Android 2.2" -- what is the application?

Comment: Wave Launcher. Free Application on the Amazon Appstore today.

Comment: @spierce7: Oh, well, I see how they're doing that. It is not "TouchEvent manipulation", per se. It's a security hole, IMHO, and so I am not going to discuss it, other than with the Android security team. The technique they are using could be used by malware to intercept touch events that the user thinks they are entering into, say, their banking app.

Comment: The security hole that you are referencing, is this the same one that was patched? If so, what version of Android is it patched in?

Comment: @CommonsWare: You're saying you can't capture touch events from a service? I don't think that's correct. I don't care enough to argue, but that statement is not correct. I've done this a few different ways, you just have to set a few flags, and implement a listener.

Answer (score 0):

Implement an `onTouchListener` and check the view or coords that it returns.  A service is just for controlling background activities using threads.

Edit:

Probably the best wasy to do this would be to override `Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(TouchEvent event)` and use a loop to pick out the `View` that was touched.  For example.

```
@Override
dispathTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.mylayout);
    for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
        // do comparison to see if event.getX() and event.getY() fall in the view.getChildAt(i).getX(), getWidth(), getY() and getHeight()
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused. So for instance, if I have a service implement onTouchListener, I can then take the event or view that it returns and then based on the location of the click, I can for instance launch an activity? Or are you saying that I can't do that with the activity?

Comment: @spierce7:  You wouldn't use a Service at all.  I will edit my answer with some more detail.

Comment: OK, I'm a bit confused as to how something like that would work then. In my mind I would have to have something from my service running in order to open up another part of my application, I guess I'll just wait for your edit.

Comment: @spierce7. sorry I was under the impression that this would be your own developed Home Screen or application, not the Home Screen or any running app.